# Why is Symfony2 ignoring my APPLICATION_ENV?

Tags: php, symfony, virtual-hosts

In my Apache virtual host, I've set my environment variable to dev:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV dev

    DocumentRoot /Users/jonathan/localhost/web
    <Directory /Users/jonathan/localhost/web>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Echoing `getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')` confirms that I've set it correctly. So why is Symfony2 still using my 'prod' environment?

Comment: are you trying to use app.php or app_dev.php?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think by default, Symfony2 reads the APPLICATION_ENV variable. If you want this to control your application, you have to add functionality in the web/app.php or web/app_dev.php. Change the following:

```php
$kernel = new AppKernel(getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'prod', false);
```